# Auto Populate a text field which is marked as external Id and Unique

Tags: process-builder, workflow

I have Accounts of 5 different record types. On Account is Custom Field, that is marked as an ExternalID and UNIQUE. Field Type =TEXT Length = 6 .
 
If an Account is identified as duplicate (based on same AccountName and Billing Post Code), the Accounts are merged. However there are situations when an Account is not a candidate for merge. In this situation we enter the ExternalID__C blank.

Leaving this field blank affects some of the other processes, and leads to confusion. We do not want to delete these records, instead want to archive them.

**I am thinking of the following approach -**

1. Create a new RecordType = 'Archive'
2. When a Account is identified as 'not candidate for merge', edit the recordtype = Archive.
3. Auto populate the ExternalID__c field as AR1, AR2

That way these Accounts will not show up in Reports when filtered on a specific record type. However these records can still be searched.

**My questions**
 
  1.Is it possible to autopopulate the text field when recordtype is chnaged to a specific value?

2.If this is not a good approach, what would be a good practice to deal with Accounts that are kind of redundant, but good to be saved in the database for reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is possible
2. Given that it sounds like your process is triggered by a manual user action(decision), you might consider a process/flow where the 'not candidate for merge' records are first created as records on a related object (ie Account Archive) via a lookup relationship (that allows you to retain/track the 'similar but unmerged' record data against the respective Account master) and then delete them from the Account object.

The idea would be to avoid unnecessary record type bloat (and associated reporting maintenance cost), search results confusion, and account hierarchy concerns while avoiding the ExternalId__c issue you mentioned above. The Archive Account record created could also be limited to only necessary field data, reducing storage costs if original Accounts records contain a lot of fields. Further, it provides users the ability to view associated archived data in a related list and to conversationally debate record differences should any disagreements 'merging' or 'mastering' arise after the fact. Lastly, if needed you could create a process/flow for unarchiving records.

There are conceivably many ways to solve this issue, but it may require a combination of standard functionality (actions, processes, flows, etc) if you are trying to avoid using code.